# Construction measure $1/2$ set in measure 1 set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $m(E)=1$.  I wish to construct a subset $A \subset E$ with $m(A)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Is the way to go about this as follows:

As $E$ is Leb measurable, (given $m_*$ is exterior or outer measure.) we know that

$$m(E)=m_*(E).$$

Then we have that

\begin{align}
m_*(E) &= \inf\{\sum_j \vert I_j \vert \} \\
&= 1
\end{align}

where the infimum is taken over all countable coverings of $E$ by closed sets. Is there a way to use the collection $\{I_j\}_j$ which is a cover for $E$ and cut the volume of each $I_j$ in half or? Or is appealing to outer measure not the way. I know for any given $\epsilon>0$, I can apprixamte $E$ from inside and outside by $\epsilon$ does this help me?

Comment: Apply IVP to the continuous function $f(x)=m(E \cap (-\infty,x))$.

Comment: so is your function defined as taking in $x$ values and spitting as output the measure of the intersection of $E$ and the interval from negative infinity to this point $x$?

Comment: and then hit that guy with Intermmediate value? Is there a more constructive way or no?

Comment: Without a constructive definition of $E$ how could there be one for $A$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Kavi's approach is actually pretty contstructive in practice. Start with $x=0$, iteratively increase or decrease to another integer until you find $n$ st $f(n) < 1/2 < f(n+1)$, then iteratively evaluated the midpoint, halve the interval size etc.

Comment: couldn't I use dilation invariance and use $\frac{1}{2}$ as my factor?